# How to properly use this jQuery script in my Next.Js app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js, script-tag

i have this script, that i was using a a plain HTML website, and import it via the `<script>` tag:

```
(function($) {
  var wa_time_out, wa_time_in;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wa__btn_popup").on("click", function() {
      if ($(".wa__popup_chat_box").hasClass("wa__active")) {
        $(".wa__popup_chat_box").removeClass("wa__active");
        $(".wa__btn_popup").removeClass("wa__active");
        clearTimeout(wa_time_in);
        if ($(".wa__popup_chat_box").hasClass("wa__lauch")) {
          wa_time_out = setTimeout(function() {
            $(".wa__popup_chat_box").removeClass("wa__pending");
            $(".wa__popup_chat_box").removeClass("wa__lauch");
          }, 400);
        }
      } else {
        $(".wa__popup_chat_box").addClass("wa__pending");
        $(".wa__popup_chat_box").addClass("wa__active");
        $(".wa__btn_popup").addClass("wa__active");
        clearTimeout(wa_time_out);
        if (!$(".wa__popup_chat_box").hasClass("wa__lauch")) {
          wa_time_in = setTimeout(function() {
            $(".wa__popup_chat_box").addClass("wa__lauch");
          }, 100);
        }
      }
    });

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
      var name = cname + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
      for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == " ") {
          c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
          return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
      }
      return "";
    }

    $("#nta-wa-gdpr").change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        setCookie("nta-wa-gdpr", "accept", 30);
        if (getCookie("nta-wa-gdpr") != "") {
          $('.nta-wa-gdpr').hide(500);
          $('.wa__popup_content_item').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('pointer-disable');
            $('.wa__popup_content_list').off('click');
          })
        }
      }
    });

    if (getCookie("nta-wa-gdpr") != "") {
      $('.wa__popup_content_list').off('click');
    } else{
      $('.wa__popup_content_list').click(function(){
        $('.nta-wa-gdpr').delay(500).css({"background" : "red", "color" : "#fff"});
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

And i imported jQuery on cdn, putting this before `</head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And i need to use this on my NextJS app.

I tried putting the same script in a file on `/public/static/script.js`

Then importing on my `_app.js` like this:

```
      <Head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </Head>
```

Also tried some other ways that i've seen on Google and here, but none works. How can i properly do this?

Comment: `script.js` uses jQuery but `<script src=".../jquery.min.js"></script>` comes after `<script src=".../script.js"></script>`. Order matters.

Comment: @Andreas i changed the order now and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What does doesn't work mean. Are the target classes and id in the jquery script present in the rendered next page?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule the divs show a WhatsApp button, and the script makes a modal appear when i click the WhatsApp button and show a window above.

My divs are all rendered in the page, of course, but the script doesn't work, when i click on the button, the modal won't appear.

I got the script here, for reference: https://codepen.io/glauberf/pen/ywJGpg
It should work exactly like on this codepen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow these steps

install jquery

```
npm install jquery
```

loader.js

```
//loader.js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

After that, the jquery will work as well

```
import '[LoaderPath]/loader.js'

...

const handleForm = () => {
  $("#date").val("data");
}
```

contact [me](https://nicholijin.com/) if you want more

Comment: Hey... What is Loader.js Here... is that is a Custom file...

Comment: Yes, Somewhere in your project folder

Comment: I can't find the loader.js file

Comment: You can create it any place in your project root.

Comment: Because it seems some were confused, you have to create loader.js manually, it's a one-line file that allows you to import jquery like you import other stuff in react.

Comment: If you want the jquery on only one file, it is no problem to write it inside of the file.

Comment: window is not defined

Answer (score 0):

place jquery script tag it in your _document.js

example in pages_document.js

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="id">
        <Head>
          <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
          <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade"/>
          <script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> // no import jquery error if you put this
        </Head>
```

Comment: 17:23  Error: Synchronous scripts should not be used. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-sync-scripts  @next/next/no-sync-scripts